# How can i set email_token_expiry time for 24 hours?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

`email_token_expiry` is a datetime field in mysql table.

views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    obj = UsersModelForm(request.POST)
    obj.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + 24 hours
    obj.save()
```

How can I set the email_token_expiry time for 24 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use timedelta as follows:

```
import datetime
obj.email_token_expiry = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same thing?